# Is there a way to specify the div something should go into in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, widget

Let's say I make multiple divs in HTML. I then create (in my case) widgets and 3D graphics in JavaScript within the HTML. (My graphics are created using the GlowScript library). Is it possible to specify which div I want the different widgets or 3D graphics to be placed in? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the document elements in your Javascript code through the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).
The simplest way is to add an id to your target elements and then use the `getElementById` method to retrieve them :

```js
let firstDiv = document.getElementById("1")
firstDiv.innerHTML = "2"
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your graphics are already in HTML form:

`document.getElementById(‘divID’).innerHTML = graphics`;

Where you can replace divID with the `ID` of the div you want and `graphics` with your HTML string.

Comment: Thank you! I don't believe my graphics are in HTML form though. I'm using GlowScript to create the graphics in JavaScript. For example, after first importing packages, the line to create a box is: var my_box=box(). How would you go about making this graphic in HTML form?

Comment: At the moment, if I use this approach it just has the text [Object Object] where I want the widget or graphic to go.

Comment: I’m not familiar with the library but it seems like your widget is not a html element. Try to look through the docs to see if you can convert it to one

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in the docs about converting it (a creator of GlowScript also didn't have information on it). You can however embed it in an iframe and I think you could use appendChild to embed the iframe into a div. However, this seems a bit clunky because I would have to include a bunch of code which  imports the libraries and a function for each iframe.

Comment: Can you link me to the docs? I can’t seem to find a library called GlowScript for Javascript

Comment: I realize that it's not really a library. It's an environment for creating 3D animations, and can be coded in Python or JavaScript. Here's the documentation: https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/index.html

Comment: Reading though the html example, some things that stand out are this line - `window.__context = {glowscript_container: ...}` and `print(x)` try to set the window.__context to the div you want and then try to use print() to display your results. You might need to have the library imported as a CDN to have print() available globally. Here is the example https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/using_javascript.html jsut scroll down